# VS Enterprise .NET Build Extensions version of System.Net.Http overrides intended 4.3.3 nuget version

Tags: visual-studio, http, nuget, enterprise-library, system.net

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise edition.  The issue I'm running into is that every time I install the latest System.Net.Http nuget package (4.3.3) into a project, the System.Net.Http reference seems to prefer to point to the VS Enterprise extensions version of System.Net.Http:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net471\lib\System.Net.Http.ddl
```

I tried everything to force it to use the nuget version including binding redirects:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.2" newVersion="4.1.1.2" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

and setting the "HintPath" in the .csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Net.Http.4.3.3\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

But it still just keeps snapping back to the above VS Enterprise extensions version.  I need to be able to use the nuget version of System.Net.Http dll because I have another library (Serilog) that depends on it.

Two questions:  (1) Why does this happen?  (2) How do I force it to ignore the VS Enterprise version of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like some problem with referencing packages in .net framework 4.6:

> If you're building a .NET Framework 4.6.x app, you should just use
>   standard references to System.Net.Http and not bring in any Nuget
>   package for System.Net.Http.

You could try to upgrade .net framework in your project to the latest release. More information about this issue: [System.Net.Http v4.2.0.0 being copied/loaded from MSBuild tooling](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25773)